# Whitelist / Blocking with chrome.webRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

so I've been trying to add whitelist ability to chrome extension, where that list can be updated via or whitelist can be totally disabled.

After checking the documentation and all possible answers here, I am still facing one weird issue, any light on it would be appreciated.

So here is the code snippet

```
//this list can be updated by user or other trigger
var allowed = ["example.com", "cnn.com", "domain.com"]; 

//this is main callback, so it can be removed from listener when needed

whiteMode = function (details) {

    //checking url to array
    var even = function(element) {
      return details.url.indexOf(element) == -1;
    }

    if (allowed.some(even) == true) {
        return {cancel: true }
    } else {
        return {cancel: false}
    }
}

//setup listener
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
   whiteMode,
   {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, 
   ["blocking"]
);
```

so that works fine itself, if user wants to disable the mode, I just call

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(whiteMode);
```

Then, if I would like to update the allowed list, I first use removeListener, then relaunch it again with new values, it does launches, however the "whiteMode" function keeps triggering twice now. By checking with console.log, I see that my new url is missing in the array on first try, then immidiately listener works again, and there is correct new array of allowed, however as it was already blocked by first trigger, it's just doing nothing.

The question, why the listener keeps doing it twice or more (if I add more items let's say), even if it was removed before added back.

Is there any way to clear up all listeners? (nothing about that in docs), been struggling with this for quite some time...

Also, tried with onHandlerBehaviorChanged, but its not helping.

Comment: Extract the function as a global `function whiteMode` so its object reference doesn't change. You seem to recreate whiteMode each time currently.

Comment: oh well, right point, it worked! you saved my day, after declaring func as global outside of other scope, works a charm!